# What's wrong with this binding? (Angular 2+)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

UPDATE 3:

Actually I found what was causing the initial issue for my code. If I use Ionic/Angular listener to bind to a button in my code - then changing the variable fro false to true - does change the UI state.

However if I use custom listener ('touchstart') then even though variable changes - it will not cause the UI refresh. I think it is due to the way angular rendering etc works. But I wish that was documented somewhere.

EDITED with code snippet + explanation that in the code snippet we have parent and child components where child's emitted event needs to change parent components visibility.

EDITED TO CLARIFY QUESTION BETTER:

In my code I have a very simple component (below) and I want to make these UI rangers to appear/disappear **dynamically** following the boolean state of the showSliders variable.

I verified that I am getting the value updated in the variable, but I guess the view only reads it the moment it renders or something like that.

So again I see that the UI is not showing when [hidden]="showSliders" (showSliders is true here) and vice versa.

But the problem is - if the page has already rendered itself in one state, then dynamic change of the variable does not cause the UI to appear/disapear.

I there an easy way to achieve that?

**In javascript I would probably just get that DIV's ID.style.display="none" once I get the boolean value. How can I do the same in angular 2+?**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ChildComponent } from '../../components/child/child'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public hidden: boolean = false; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  toggleButton() {
    this.hidden = !this.hidden;
    console.log(this.hidden);
  }

  getEvent($event) {
    console.log($event);
    this.hidden = $event;
  }
}

// CHILD:

import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<button block ion-button (click)="toggleButton()">Hide Toggle (Child)</button>'
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Output() onSomeEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  boolean: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello ChildComponent Component');
  }

  toggleButton() {
    this.onSomeEvent.emit(this.boolean);
    console.log("pressed Child button")
  }

}
```

```html
// PARENT VIEW:

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Just playground
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 

  <ion-item [hidden]="hidden">
    <ion-range>
      <ion-icon range-left small name="sunny"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon range-right name="sunny"></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>

  <button block ion-button (click)="toggleButton()">Hide Toggle (Parent)</button>
  <child (onSomeEvent)="getEvent($event)"></child>

</ion-content>



<ion-footer>
  
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Did the answer help you to solve the problem or you need more help with that?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the binding, indeed you need to learn more.

Comment: hey both i re clarified my question here

Comment: oh damn i am just stupid...I thought I am alternating the value but I was not doing it...DAMN:( this works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my research I discovered that if an UI component (like "ion-toolbar") has conditional visibility set via *ngIf or [hidden] attribute bound to a variable - then changing this variable via Ionic/Angular listeners (click, tap etc) will dynamically update UI, while if DOM level listeners are used (.addEventListener) then UI will not update even though the variable that is bound to the UI state has changed.

Example (not real code example but conceptually):

```
isItHidden:boolean = false;

<ion-toolbar #toolbar [hidden]=isItHidden (click)="changeVisibility()"><ion-toolbar>

@Viewchild('toolbar'): toolbar;

toolbarElem = this.toolbar.nativeElement;
toolbarElem.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `*ngIf=""` structural directive.

```html
<div *ngIf="!showSliders"> 
  <div [hidden]="bottomPanelStylesState!=='line'">
    <ion-range min="0" max="100%" pin="true" color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="svgchild.lineSlider">
      <ion-icon range-left small name="contrast"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon range-right name="contrast"></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="bottomPanelStylesState!=='fill'">
    <ion-range min="0%" max="100%" pin="true" color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="svgchild.fillSlider">
      <ion-icon range-left small name="moon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon range-right name="moon"></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="bottomPanelStylesState!=='filter'">
    <ion-range min="0%" max="100%" pin="true" color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="svgchild.filterSlider">
       <ion-icon range-left small name="leaf"></ion-icon>
       <ion-icon range-right name="leaf"></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </div>
</div>
```

The difference between `[hidden]` and `*ngIf=""` is that, `hidden` applies the CSS `display:hidden` prperty and `*ngIf=""` removes the element from the DOM.

Here, sometimes using the `[hidden]` can cause issues as that can be overwritten. That might be the issue.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply, I will try it right away, but I fear the problem is not with the fact the item is not getting proper render state. It is that once later on in the app the variable "showSliders" changes dynamically via onSelected event => the UI still remains in its previous state ignoring the new value of the variable. I will add a snippet

Comment: I double checked and definitely I am getting the variable "showSliders" changing its boolean value - but I still don't get it - how do I send a "propagation" or a command to the DIV to tell it "hey cmon the value of the thing you are looking at changed - change your state please"...

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Hope you got this sorted.

Comment: yes I did found out the cause - see my update 3. It was connected with the fact I was using "addEventListener"s and not in built Ionic listeners. Now I got around it. But thank you for your comments and help that encouraged me:)

Comment: Great that you could solve it @SergeyRudenko . So It'd be great if you can add that as an answer and accept it. Might be helpful for the people who're looking into the same issue.